# Override Eslint rule only for specific code fragment

Tags: exception, comments, config, eslint, linter

Is it possible to enable Eslint custom rule via comments for some **code fragment** only? Eg. I'd like to change rule setting only for single function in file (`func2`) and the rest should use global Eslint setting. Something like this:

```
func1() {
...
};

/* eslint-enable sonarjs/cognitive-complexity: ["error", 16] */
func2() {
...
}
/* eslint-disable sonarjs/cognitive-complexity: ["error", 16] */

func3() {
 ...
}
```

...so only `func2` can reach 16 points of complexity - other functions shouldn't exceed complexity value from global settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this but only on a per file bais. In your eslintrc file you can do

```
override: {
  files: [...],
  rules: {...},
}
```